# (Unity + 2D) Change UI Button position issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

The last few days I've been stuck with a headache of a problem in Unity.

Okay, I won't go into details with my game, but I've made a super-simple example which represents my issue.

I have a 2D scene these components:
[image: Basic scene]

When the scene loads, and I tap the button this script executes:

```
Vector3 pos = transform.position;
pos.x -= 10;
transform.position = pos;
```

I have also tried this code:

```
transform.position = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
```

The problem is, that when I click the button, the x-pos of the object sets to -1536 which is not as expected. Picture shows the scene after the button has been clicked. Notice the Rect Transform values:
[image: After button click]

So I did a little Googling and found out about ScreenToWorldPoint, WorldToScreenPoint etc but no of these conversions solves my problem.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing someting here, which probably is right in front of my, but I simply can't figure out what.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Best regards.

Comment: Maybe try using localposition instead of position. Also, did both attempts in change transform.position give the exact same result, or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `transform.localposition = new Vector3(0,0,0);` as your button is a child of multiple game objects. You could also try using `transform.TransformPoint`, which should [just convert localpos to worldpos.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html)

Comment: That did it - how could I miss that! Thank you so much, Penguin!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are using `transform.position` instead of `rectTransform.anchoredPosition`.

While it's true that UI elements are still `GameObjects` and do have the normal `Transform` component accessible in script, what you see in the editor is a representation of the `RectTransform` that is built on top. This is a special inspector window for UI elements, which use the anchored positioning system so you can specify how the edges line up with their parent elements.

When you set a `GameObject`'s `transform.position`, you are providing a world space position specified in 3D scene units (meters by default). This is different from a local position relative to the canvas or parent UI element, specified in reference pixels (the reference pixel size is determined by the canvas "Reference Resolution" field).

A potential issue with your use of `Camera.WorldToScreenPoint` is that that function returns a position *specified in pixels*. Whereas, as mentioned before, setting the `transform.position` is specified in *scene units* (i.e. meters by default) and not relative to the parent UI element. The inspector, though, knows it's a UI element so instead of showing you that value, it is showing you the world position translated to the UI's local coordinates.

In other words, when you set the position to zero, you are getting the indices of whatever pixels happen to be over the scene's zero point in your main camera's view, and converting those pixel numbers to meters, and moving the element there. The editor is showing you a position in *reference pixels* (which are not necessarily screen pixels, check your canvas setting) relative to the object's parent UI element. To verify, try tilting your camera a bit and note that the value displayed will be different.

So again you would need to use `rectTransform.anchoredPosition`, and you would further need to ensure that the canvas resolution is the same as your screen resolution (or do the math to account for the difference). The way the object is anchored will also matter for what the `rectTransform` values refer to.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying, Joseph! That was really, really, really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your button is inside of another object. You want to be changing the local position. `transform.localPosition -= new Vector3(10, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

As @Joseph has clearly explained, you have to make changes on your `RectTransform` for your UI components, instead of change `Transform`.

To achieve what you want, do it like this:

```
RectTransform rectTransform = this.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
Vector2 anchoredPos = rectTransform.anchoredPosition;
anchoredPos.x -= 10;
rectTransform.anchoredPosition = anchoredPos;
```

Just keep in mind that this `10` are not your 3D world space units (like meters or centimeters).

Answer (score 0):

Try these things because I did not understand what you were trying to do

Try using transform.deltaposition
Go to the canvas and go then scale with screen size then! You can use transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x -10,transform.position.y, transform.positon.z)

And if this doesn't work
transform.Translate(new Vector3(transform.deltaposition.x - 10,transform.deltaposition.y, transform.deltaposition.z);

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quick, Saifkhan! I appreciate that! :-) Unfortunately, the first script does not solve the issue (positions are still way off) and the second one is not working - it appears my Unity cannot recognise "deltaposition". Basically what I'm trying to achieve is a script that can place UIButtons at a specific position.

Answer (score 0):

I have a better idea. Instead of changing the positions of the buttons, why not change the values that the buttons represent?

Moving Buttons

Remember that the buttons are GameObjects, and every gameobject has a position vector in its transform. So if your button is named ButtonA, then in your code you want to get a reference to that.

```
 GameObject buttonA = GameObject.Find("ButtonA");
```

//or you can assign the game object from the inspector

Once you have a reference to the button, you can proceed in moving it. So let's imagine that we want to move ButtonA 10 units left.

```
Vector3 pos = buttonA.transform.position;
 pos.X -= 10f;
 buttonA.transform.position = pos;
```

Comment: This does make sense, but for some reason, it won't work. I tried to place my ButtonA at position 0,0,0 in Unity - and then I tested your script. After clicking on the button, and expecting it to move -10 on the x-axis, instead it get a x-position of -600. I really don't get this.